Add a patch in kustomization that replaces the default namespace with a new namespace name
Working with k8s, I have a kustomization file that builds my app and all it's resources. A lot of those resources(files) run in the default namespace. I want to add a patch on the kustomization file that changes only deployments and services running in the default namespace to a new namespace of my choice. How can I do this?

This question would be easier to answer if it included an [mcve] demonstrating the problem you're trying to solve. Based on your description it sounds like you may need to rethink the structure of your kustomize project, but without more details it's hard to tell.
